# angular how to get a drop down selection input with options from the server

Tags: angular

console error:

> AddTaskComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of >undefined
>      at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

html:

```
<select ng-model="memberlist">

    <option ng-repeat="data in memberlist" value="{{data.name}}">{{data.name}}</option>

</select>
```

component code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.onGetMember()
}
onGetMember() {
    this.helper = this.pagedata.getMemberNames()
    this.helper.subscribe(
      res => {
        // this.memberlist = res.json();
        this.memberlist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
        console.log("from angular component for add task: ");
        console.log(this.memberlist);
      });
  }
```

the data does appear on the inspector console but not on the drop down list.

> {_body: "[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"}]", status: 200, ok: >true, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to access the `_body` property.

Also, use the optional parameter `?` prevent throwing an exception if the object is null

```
<option *ngFor="let data of memberlist._body" [value]="data?.name">{{data?.name}}</option>
```

Comment: ng-repeat is not present in angular v.2+

Comment: @AnoopSurendran Opps. u are absolutely right. updated it

Comment: @sachila thats the solution. I have removed downvote as well

Comment: now getting this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_body' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: combination of all the fixes: 1. <select [(ngModel)]  2. <option *ngFor="let data of memberlist" [value]="data?.name">{{data?.name}}</option> 3. this.memberlist = res.json();

Answer (score 0):

This is because the the format of data you fetch from service. The solution is you have to make the services of observable type. So that you will get the json on subscribe part. 
In your case  the response is like:

```
{_body: "[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"}]", status: 200, ok: >true, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, …}
```

And it is assigned to this.memberlist.

try `this.memberlist = res.json();`